# mysql: unique constraint on multiple columns: IMPOSSIBLE to update just caps letter

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table with unique constrain on 3 columns:

PROBLEM:
Let's say one row is

```
col5      col7     col9
lemon    orange   apple
```

if I try to modify that very same row to (just update to capital letter):

```
col5     col7     col9
lemon    Orange   apple
```

I get the error Duplicate entry lemon-Orange-apple. Basically mysql compares the proposed modification, not just to the other rows of the table, but also to itself, the modified row (before the modification).
After some troubleshooting, I believe it's related to LONGTEXT... but not sure how to solve it...

QUESTION

Is there a way to keep the table/columns case insensitive, but let understand mysql that I'm just modifying a row, so it doesn't have to compare the row values to itself (the modified row)?

---

UPDATE (more details)

Is anybody able to reproduce this problem?

Server version: 10.4.17-MariaDB

After running SHOW CREATE TABLE this is the result:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` 
( `post_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'my comment', 
`col1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'unique or NULL', 
 `col2` varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
 `col3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
 `col4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'CONSTRAIN: Accepts only NULL and post_ID', 
 `col5` longtext NOT NULL, 
 `col6` longtext NOT NULL, 
 `col7` longtext NOT NULL, 
 `col8` longtext NOT NULL, 
 `col9` longtext NOT NULL, 
 `col10` longtext NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_ID`), UNIQUE KEY `col1` (`col1`), 
 UNIQUE KEY `col5` (`col5`(255),`col7`(255),`col9`(255)) USING HASH COMMENT '!!!These columns together MUST be unique!!!', 
 KEY `key_1` (`col3`), KEY `key_2` (`col4`) ) 
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=120 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Insert test data:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` 
(`post_ID`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`, `col6`, `col7`, `col8`, `col9`, `col10`) 
 VALUES (NULL, NULL, '', NULL, NULL, 'apple', '', 'orange', '', 'apple', '');
```

Try to Update orange to Orange (just by typing the word Orange into phpMyAdmin field):

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `col7` = 'Orange' WHERE `mytable`.`post_ID` = 120
```

Error:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'apple-Orange-apple' for key 'col5'
```

TRIED SOLUTIONS

I tried to modify collation to utf8mb4_bin or latin7_general_cs (as proposed on other questions) for CaSe sEnSiTivE comparisons; it solves the problem of modify only cApS, but it doesn't work for me because all searches became CaSe sEnSiTivE (obviously) and when I search the table for "orange" it will not find "Orange".

Tried also to alternate make table utf8mb4_bin and columns utf8mb4_general_ci (and viceversa), but with no luck. Same problems.
After some troubleshooting, I believe it's related to LONGTEXT... but not sure how to solve it...

Comment: You use case-independent collation. Use collation with `_cs` postfix (or binary). Or specify the collation in the conditional expressions. Also remember that the table data uses database/table/column collation whereas string literal provided into the query text uses connection collation.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support arrays so I don't understand the title.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry: I meant "constraint" not array!

Comment: @Akina Thanks, but I can't find "utf8mb4_cs"  in phpMyAdmin... I can only find cs in latin collations. Using latin2_general_cs or latin7_general_cs will be the same? What do you thing?

Comment: @Akina cs collation doesn't work :( . I need searches case insensitive, but be able to modify SAME row from "orange" to Orange...

Comment: what does your update statement look like? Are you using REPLACE or INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY?

Comment: I can't find any way to reproduce your problem. Updating works fine. mysql will only keep you from inserting a duplicate column.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey just using UPDATE... SET... WHERE....

Comment: @GarrGodfrey It's not in the query, because even if I just try to modify orange to Orange in phpMyAdmin, I get the same error !!! PS Can be that table is corrupted? Do you know a way to verify that?

Comment: do you know what version of mysql?

Comment: and if they are LONGTEXT, mysql requires a LENGTH to be set on the index

Comment: *cs collation doesn't work :(* if so then you use it incorrectly. *be able to modify SAME row from "orange" to Orange..* - column collation must be case-sensitive, *I need searches case insensitive* - case-insensitive operands collation must be specified explicitly in the condition, like `WHERE column = 'literal' COLLATE needed_ci_collation`.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8.0.13 supports functional indexes.  So, you can do what you want using a unique index:

```
create unique index idx_t_col1_col2_col3 on t( (convert(col1 using binary)), (convert(col2 using binary)), (convert(col3 using binary)) )
```

In older versions of 8.0, you can mimic this by creating computed columns and then creating an index on those columns.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87d8f3d7570cc4dbfde8582a62a9855c) is a simpler example using only one column.

Comment: It's not clear this is what the OP wants. This would allow duplicate columns where they differ only in case, but he seems to just want to be able to update them...which makes it unclear why an error is produced

Comment: I've posted more details in my answer, can you please guys get a look at it... There must be something wrong I've done... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED!!]

By luck and chance, problem is solved!

Not sure how, but these are the steps I did:

1. Following Garr Godfrey's comment ("...if they are LONGTEXT, mysql requires a LENGTH to be set on the index") I added length (1000) to the index.

[at this step still not working, but useful for next steps]

2. Brute/Force Restart the server (actually the battery died :o !!)
3. in phpMyAdmin: Optimize Table (in the hope that this was rebuilding the index)

TA DAAA! Now we are back on business : ) !

Thanks to everybody for your support!